# How to move game-development tagged questions from Stack Overflow to here?

Tags: discussion, migration

There are currently 1,475 [questions tagged game-development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game-development) on Stack Overflow. These would all be great seed material for this new Game Development site. Would it be a good idea for a moderator to move those questions here? Is there any reason it shouldn't happen? (for example, how would it affect my SO rep, having asked a number of these myself?)

Comment: that would be nice to see

Comment: indeed, but we might need http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3/programming-questions-here-or-belongs-on-stackoverflow done.

Comment: While it *would* be nice to see - I think it would set a bad precedent, giving some sites (technical ones) an unfair edge over others. Which has nothing to do with whether SE will do it, of course. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This wouldn't be done until the site proves it can survive public beta for the required 60  to 90 days.

Comment: Oo scary, I hope we survive!! :)

Answer (score 13):

I don't think that migrating every single game development question from Stack Overflow to this site is a good idea.  We shouldn't be retroactively moving questions.  It would just be a mess over all.  The reputation issue that you mentioned is just one small issue amongst many.

The questions on Stack Overflow that are already there are asked and done.  If someone is unsatisfied with their answer, or rather wants to ask a new, game-development-related question, they are free to ask it over here on Game Dev.  That way they will get fresh, possibly more relevant answers from experts who actually work in the field of game development.

I don't know, it just feels like a complicated mess that is more or less unnecessary.  I'm sure the admins will agree as well.

Comment: To avoid the mess you could migrate X questions per day or cause the questions to not appear in the current list unless another action besides migration has occurred.

Comment: @TomWij, speed or Q/days isn't the only issue, as @Justin points out, reputation is a *major* issue, and there are others.

Comment: I agree that moving is not that great an idea. There are questions there from well over a year ago which, while unlikely, may need new answers/be out of date. Justin L made a good point that if the users want the answer they can just ask it here and get the most up to date info available.

Answer (score 0):

I agree. Some of the questions tagged as game-development are of particular interest to game developers, but still are by no means offtopic on the general programming stack overflow. Why removing them? Is every game developer required to ask questions only here?

If such move will be prepared, I will probably consider removing the game-development tag from some questions.